# Trap backspace key on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

On the iPhone, I've tried to find a way to trap and act upon the backspace key pressed event. But cannot find a way to do that!! There sure must be one such way documented in the SDK right?

/John

Comment: There is no real backspace key because there is no real keyboard and thus nothing to trap. Why would you want to "trap" a "key" in the iPhone context tho?

Comment: Lol, is anything "real"?
In my reality there is a backspace key on a very existing keyboard on the iPhone. I'd like to trap its keypress because I'd like to act upon it, for example delete a selected widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your UITextField which is taking the input, set your controller object to be the text field's delegate and implement the

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

delegate method in your controller.

This method should be called for every editing event (keypress).  I believe that you should be able to look for a blank replacement string to tell that characters are being removed by the backspace key.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess that could be used. It complicates this method of mine even further though... It's a pity there is no explicit way of getting such an event.  
Thx!